# change wordpress upload url to subdomain on xampp local

Tags: subdomains, localhost, xampp, virtual-hosts

Firstly, I am sorry for bad English Language

I want to make a site using wp on local with xampp 3.2.2 (win10)

To avoid future problems (e.g changing domain after moving to live or changing media file path in db) i stablish a virtual host & a subdomain by putting this code in **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xyz.com
    ServerAlias xyz.com
    ServerAdmin admin@xyz.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/xyz"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dl.xyz.com
    ServerAlias dl.xyz.com
    ServerAdmin admin@dl.xyz.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/xyz/dl"
</VirtualHost>
```

& this code to **httpd.conf**

```
Alias /xyz "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/xyz/"
<Directory "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/xyz/">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

- then i check subdomain to making sure it's working by making simple index.html to "dl" DIR (dl.xyz.com) & work Properly.
- then I install wp and after some configuration I follow this article step to change WordPress default upload path:

https://www.webnots.com/move-wordpress-images-folder-to-subdomain/

This is my database change:

upload_path:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/xyz/dl/uploads
```

upload_url_path:

```
http://dl.xyz.com/uploads
```

I change "dl" DIR permission As described here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mX2WsUfW_x4
In this way: dl Folder properties >> sharing Tab >> Advanced Sharing >> check share this folder >> Permissions >> select Everyone as username >> check Allow option for "full Control" "Change" "Read" this is 777 permissions

now when i want to upload file to media this error appeared:

> Unable to create directory C:/xampp/htdocs/xyz/dl/uploads/2019/02. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Comment: Please put your permissions procedures inside the question instead of linking to the video.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was / in upload_path:
That most change to\
C:/xampp/htdocs/xyz/dl/uploads
C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\dl\uploads